# Ionic select multiple images or videos from gallery

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm developing a mobile application in Ionic Angular and I don't seem to be able to find a plugin that supports being able to select multiple pieces of media as well as both images and videos.

So far I've come across and tried two:

### Ionic native camera

Unfortunately this plugin only has a `getPicture()` method which only allows for the selection of **one** item (image/video).

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera/

### Ionic native image-picker

Unfortunately this plugin does allow for the selection of multiple items with `getPictures()` yet it only selects images. This function supposedly has an option `allow_video: true` in its invocation parameters but I've tried this out yet videos don't show up in the gallery. There's also an open [github issue](https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/ImagePicker/issues/74) since 2017 about this with no response.

https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/ImagePicker

My question here is, does anyone know of an Ionic plugin that would allow me to open the gallery and allow the user to select multiple pieces of media - both images and video?
The returned result would preferably be a file URI for each selected item but that is not a necessity.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what the issue with the ImagePicker plugin?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph The ImagePicker plugin does not allow for the selection of videos as I explained above. Supposedly it has an `allow_video` boolean attribute but this does not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple files with the ionic plugin I am also unable to find but you can use Html file tag to get the desired type of files.

```
HTML code
    <input type="file" multiple name="files[]">

TS code    
    files: FileList;
    public testup(event){ files=event.target.files;}
```